# How do I efficiently pass multiple req.query values from Express to Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I set up a GET route with Express.JS which accepts multiple queries, none are required, and I can pass any combination to get different results.

I do it like so:

```
router.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    let query = {};

    if (req.query.paramOne) {
        query.paramOne = req.query.paramOne;
    }

    if (req.query.paramTwo) {
        query.paramTwo = req.query.paramTwo;
    }

    if (req.query.paramThree) {
        query.paramThree = req.query.paramThree;
    }

    if (req.query.paramFour) {
        query.paramFour = req.query.paramFour;
    }

    db.find(query).then(record => {
        res.json(record);
    });
});
```

This does exactly what I want; I can pass Mongoose any number of query options to filter my results. However, I can't help but think there's a more efficient way to do this without four if statements.

I tried doing:

```
db.find({
    paramOne: req.query.paramOne,
    paramTwo: req.query.paramTwo,
    paramThree: req.query.paramThree,
    paramFour: req.query.paramFour
}).then(record => {
    res.json(record);
})
```

But this only worked if I passed in all four parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these answers work. Based on the second, I wondered if I even needed to create a variable to pass to the query. Turns out, I can just do:

```
router.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    db.find(req.query).then(record => res.json(record));
});
```

Thank you @peteb and @rahul-sharma !

Answer (score 1):

If the keys on `query` map  1 to 1 to the keys on `req.query` then you could iterate over the `req.query` keys and create the `query` object via [`Array#reduce()`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
router.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  let query = Object.keys(req.query).reduce((mappedQuery, key) => {
    let param = req.query[key]
    if (param) {
      mappedQuery[key] = param
    }

    return mappedQuery
  }, {})

  db.find(query).then(record => res.json(record))
})
```

Comment: Okay, like you said, this works perfectly as long as the req.query properties are named the same as the query properties. It's probably best practice to do it that way, anyway.

Comment: @burningserenity not sure how passing an unvalidated request query string directly to your database is a better approach than performing some validation against the request prior to passing that to your database. The other answer opens your code up to security issues. Not sure why this is no longer the correct/better answer in your viewpoint.

Comment: how would I pass a query that would cause damage? Wouldn't that be difficult since I'm just doing a find query?